# Spark coming from distributor cap pin

Tags: vw, ignition, spark-plug-wires, distributor, fox

recently I have noticed some random engine misfires. I've checked my spark plugs and wires and haven't noticed anything unusual. I have checked for sparks at night and there were no sparks coming from wires or near the spark plugs. However there was a small spark coming from one pin of distributor cap where wire connects. I pulled out the wire and checked for corrosion or anything unusual on wire contact but it was good, also checked the distributor cap pin and distributor cap itself - again it seems to be ok, no cracks. I pushed the wire back in place on cap pin, started the engine and it worked just fine. However this thing repeats. Could it be that the connection between distributor cap pin and wire is loose? Do you guys have any ideas what could I do to prevent the spark coming?

Comment: Make / Model / Year / Mileage on vehicle?  Did you pull the distributor cap off the car and look inside?  Anything look odd to you?

Comment: More than likely you have carbon tracking inside your distributor cap which is allowing the spark to find its way to ground. Pull the cap and see if there's a line of carbon from one of the terminals (either coil or spark plug wire) going towards the base.

Comment: VW fox 2004 1.4 liter gasoline engine. I have not pulled the cap off. Will check for carbon. Thanks!

Comment: When they're cleaned, also check if the cap or cables aren't cracked anywhere. If you bend the spark plug cable, and cracks show up, it's time to replace them. When it gets wet, the spark will be grounded through water in the cracks, before firing the spark plug. Maybe check the sparkplug isolators(white cylinder on top) for cracks.